# How to change the default image location in the Django ImageField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, imagefield

Having trouble trying to change where Django looks for the default image in the ImageField. I am trying to store a default image within a folder in my "media" file.

Code from models.py below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='profile_pics/default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
```

When I load the page I get a 404 error:

Not Found: /media/default.jpg
   [21/Apr/2020 18:11:48] "GET /media/default.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1795

Any ideas on how to add the "profile_pics" piece to the path?

Answer (score 0):

add media path to your `urlpatterns` in DEBUG mode

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I do have that path in my urlpatterns.  Things work fine if I use the account I set up has an image to use.  I just cant get things to work when I want it to fall back on a default.

Answer (score 0):

you have to copy a image with `default.jpg` in media/profile_pics directory and use it for your default image for users

Comment: Not sure I understand.  I do have an image called "default.jpg" saved within the "profile_pics" folder in the "media" directory.  Don't know what is happening

Comment: I just notice that you called your picture with wrong link, your link is `/media/default.jpg` but your image is on `/media/profile_pics/default.jpg`,
call your image with right link and it will work ;)